# How to solve ExcelJS 'Object doesn't support property or method assign' exception in IE 11

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-11, exceljs

I use the component ExcelJS in my React application. The component works perfectly in all the major browsers (Chrome, Firefox, Edge), however in Internet Explorer it throws an exception related to the Javascript method assign():

*Object doesn't support property or method 'assign'*

I know that the issue is not strictly related to the ExcelJS component but maybe somebody has any solution for this?

Comment: there is no work around for this, except you want to do poly-filling

Comment: @0.sh I am open to everything, since this issue is a showstopper for my project

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign#Polyfill

Comment: @0.sh thanks for the suggestion but how fan I apply a polyfill to an external package?

Answer (score 1):

You may consider to add at the top of your entry point (file)

```
import 'core-js'
```

At the moment [core-js polyfill library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/core-js) is the easiest way to make Cross Browser Support